# Who is responsible for maintenance and eventual design changes for planes that the manufacturer has gone broke?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Sorry for the wrong vocabulary, I am not someone from the aviation industry.

There was an [incident (?) in a Foker 100 in Australia](https://simpleflying.com/virgin-australia-f100-hypoxia/). Let's now imagine that there is some project change that has to be done. Foker is out of business for years now, who is responsible for doing this change? And paying for it?

A similar question also applies: where do aircraft parts that have to be substituted come from, so planes are still able to fly?

Comment: Those divisions of the company that manufactured parts and carried out maintenance and repair work were taken over by Stork N.V.; it is now known as Stork Aerospace Group. Stork Fokker exists to sustain remarketing of the company's existing aircraft: it refurbishes and resells F 50s and F 100s, and has converted a few F 50s to transport aircraft. Special projects included the development of an F50 maritime patrol variant and an F100 executive jet.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!